# Are there other programming techniques?

Tags: objective-c, c

I have realized that most of the problems that I solve on a day to day basis are done via two programming techniques: iteration or recursion.

Are there other techniques out there? Any book recommendations or online references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the programming techniques that you use to solve the problems can be divided into types of algorithms (not into the loop or technique they use in there program, like you mentioned). some of the methods are..

```
1. Divide and conquer
2. greedy
3. dynamic programming
```

you can refer this [link](http://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/wiki/pub/ABI/DiscretMathWS10/runtime.pdf) to read more..

Comment: Ralph, I knew that there had to be something out there. So I guess I'm looking for algorithms then. Thanks for sending me on the right track.